# simplifying redundant script in jquery to activate items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 rows of items (svgs and their descriptions) with near identical markup; I've just given each container an additional identifying class in order to differentiate between them. I want it so that when I click on an svg of one item in one row, it doesn't deactivate the others. The events happening in each row should be independent of each other.

```
$('.container-a .holder').on('click', function() {
      var itemId = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
      console.log(itemId);
      $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
      $('.container-a .description').removeClass('activated');
      $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
    });

    $('.container-b .holder').on('click', function() {
      var itemId = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
      console.log(itemId);
      $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
      $('.container-b .description').removeClass('activated');
      $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
    });

    $('.container-c .holder').on('click', function() {
      var itemId = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
      console.log(itemId);
      $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
      $('.container-c .description').removeClass('activated');
      $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
    });
```

This is what I was working with before, however, it deactivates everything else after something has been clicked, rather than only deactivating everything else in the row.

```
$('.holder').on('click', function() {
  var itemId = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
  console.log(itemId);
  $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
  $('.description').removeClass('activated');
  $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
});
```

here's my html

```
<div class="container-a container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="desc-container">

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="container-b container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="desc-container">

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-c container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
      <img src="src.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="desc-container">

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can break this down into one click function instead of 3?

Comment: put it in a named function..

Comment: Give all three a common class name (`.container`?) and use it instead. Alternatively, use `$('.container-a .holder, .container-b .holder, .container-c .holder').on('click', ...`

Comment: It would be great if you will put your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would give us more chances to help if you provide html code, but for now you could try

```
function change(element){
  var itemId = element.attr('data-itemid');
  console.log(itemId);
  $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
  $(element).find('.description').removeClass('activated');
  $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
}

$('.container-a .holder').on('click', function() {
      change(this);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it all comes down to finding a way to select the  `description` element.

I believe this will work:

```
$('.holder').on('click', function() {
  var itemId = $(this).attr('data-symptomid');
  console.log(itemId);
  $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
  //$('.container-c .description').removeClass('activated');
  $(this).find('.description').removeClass('activated');

  $('.item-'+itemId).addClass('activated');
});
```

Comment: How it will work buddy? `.container-a` & `container-b` looking for `var itemId = element.attr('data-itemid');`, but in your code it's not like that. Please update your code.

Comment: @Shiladitya Didn't notice they used different attributes, updated answer

Comment: that was my fault, in copying an older version of the code over i forgot to change the variable. you were right initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can move a part of the code to a general function:

```
$('.container-a .holder').on('click', function() {
  updateClasses('.container-a .description', $(this).attr('data-itemid'));
});

$('.container-b .holder').on('click', function() {
  updateClasses('.container-b .description', $(this).attr('data-itemid'));
});

$('.container-c .holder').on('click', function() {
  updateClasses('.container-c .description', $(this).attr('data-itemid'));
});

function updateClasses(container, itemId) {
  console.log(itemId);
  $('.holder').removeClass('activated');
  $(container).removeClass('activated');
  $('.item-' + itemId).addClass('activated');
}
```

Note that it may be even simpler, depending of how your HTML file looks like.

Comment: For that matter, you can get rid of declaring `itemId` as a variable as it's only every used once inside each click handler.